# How to fix delays/lag in python script

Tags: python

I have my python script that executes an mp3 when the current time matches the time specified in a text file. However everything works well but I notice a lag and delay of around 18 seconds before mplayer plays the mp3 file.

Is there anyway of making my python script better in order to get rid of the 18 seconds lag and make the mp3 file play instantaneously?

Here is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# import libraries

import json 
import urllib2 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import datetime 
import playsound 
import os 
import subprocess

dateSTR = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')


f = open('/home/pi/test.txt','r') 
messagetest = f.read() 
newnametest = messagetest.replace("\n","") 
f.close()


if (dateSTR) == (newnametest):


    os.system("mplayer -ao alsa:device=bluealsa /home/pi/test.mp3")
```

Comment: I don't seen any loop on your code, do you run the script manually?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a loop, something like:

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
...
done = []
while 1:
    dateSTR = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
    if (dateSTR) == (newnametest) and not dateSTR in done:
        done.append(dateSTR)
        os.system("mplayer -ao alsa:device=bluealsa /home/pi/test.mp3")
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you please tell me the purpose of the loop?

Comment: I use cron job to execute the script

Comment: Check if the system isn't running other crons at the sometime, which may be causing teh delay.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me how you were running the script. Cronjob is the correct way to do it, but you can also use it on a background loop, i.e.:  `nohup python /path/to/my/script.py &`

Comment: Can you show us the content of `/home/pi/test.txt` ?

Comment: so using in my crontab -e I need to insert this: `nohup python /path/to/my/script.py &`
also your code it gives an error saying: Traceback (most recent call last):
  `File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    minutes.append(dateSTR)
NameError: name 'minutes' is not defined`

Comment: sure here it is :

`14:15`

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused. Why do you need to check the time if you run the script on a cronjob? does it run every minute? Why not running only at `14:15`?

Comment: right ok let me make it more clear. the time in the text file changes everyday and I do not monitor the text file. Hence the reason I have this part in my code: `if (dateSTR) == (newnametest):`

So whenever the current time matches the time in the text file, the music is played but like I mentioned in my OP it has a delay of 18 seconds. 

The reason why I am using a cronjob is for checking the current time against the time in the text file. I know this might not be the best thing to do but I am out of ideas.

On a different note, you said to use `nohup` do I have to put that in cron?

Comment: *text file changes everyday* -  why don't you create a cronjob directly instead of a text file?

Comment: I have another separate script that updates the text file from a website using beautifulsoup etc. so I cannot use cron for this purpose.

Comment: could you please give a clearer code with the loop? as it gives me the following: `File "test.py", line 31, in <module> minutes.append(dateSTR) NameError: name 'minutes' is not defined`

Comment: Small typo, fixed.

Comment: so I wouldnt need cronjob now? I just run the script with the loop and it would execute when the time(s) are matched?

Comment: How much time does mplayer take to load?

Comment: around 18 seconds

Comment: Based on that, the problem seems to be on the time mplayer takes to load and not on the script or cron.

Comment: Is there any better music player that is fast and can be used in python?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting `mplayer` in a subprocess before you actually need it as:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('mplayer -slave -idle -ao alsa:device=bluealsa', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

That should start up `mplayer` and have it waiting for when you need it. Then, when you want to play a file, do:

```
p.communicate(input=b'loadfile /home/pi/test.mp3\n')
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: sorry it doesnt work at all. I tried to use your method but the mp3 file is not played at all.

Comment: do you think I need to add your code in a specific place in my python script?

Comment: You should add the `Popen` as early in the script as possible. But how are you measuring the 18 seconds. The `crontab` system itself has significant delays.

Comment: yep added the Popen in the beginning of my script before `dateSTR = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')`. And I stopped crontab and I used `nohup` instead but forget the 18 seconds delay the mp3 file doesnt play at all

Comment: just these ones but they dont really matter I think: `Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-6.2.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.`

Comment: Yes, I get those same messages, but it still works for me. Are you including the `b` before the `loadfile /home/pi/test.mp3\n`?

Comment: And do you see messages like: `Playing /home/pi/test.mp3.`?

Comment: out of ideas here.